# React native how to drag card view out of ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop, scrollview, z-index

I am currently using ScrollView to hold all my cards like

```
<ScrollView>
    <Card id={1}/>
    <Card id={2}/>
</ScrollView>
```

`Card` is a customised component which is basically just a View with certain width and height. 
I used PanResponder to define the drag animation and attach the handlers to each of the Card.

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
          this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: this.state.pan.y._value});
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null, {dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y},
      ]),

      onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
        this.state.pan.flattenOffset()
      }
});
```

So `Card` component just render the animated view like

```
    <Animated.View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
       ...
    </Animated.View>
```

I can drag the card anywhere inside the scroll view, the part overflow the scroll view will be hided. how I can make the Card on top of the scrollView, then I can drag and show it anywhere across the screen.

The interesting thing that I found when I change `ScrollView` to `View`, then the `Card` can be dragged on top of the `View`. It only work on iOS, Android still be the same as `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do won't work on Android. This is because RN don't support `overflow:visible` in Android as [documented](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/known-issues.html#the-overflow-style-property-defaults-to-hidden-and-cannot-be-changed-on-android).

> The overflow style property defaults to hidden and cannot be changed on Android

This means you would have to play with the hierarchy of the container views, and think of a workaround that will have the cards contained in a much larger container or duplicated into another layer.

Comment: When I use `ScrollView` or `FlatList` to wrap the cards, both Android and iOS will hide the content of the overflow part.
When I user `View` to wrap the cards, Android will hide the overflow content and iOS works well.

Comment: That's probably related to the fact you are not setting `overflow:visible` expilictly. In `View` it defaults to true, but I think `ScrollView` changes that per item unless specified otherwise. I'm basing that assumption on this doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#removeclippedsubviews

Comment: You are right, when setting `overflow:visible`, the iOS works as expected, but not Android, thank you for your reply.